# Configure babel to look for modules in installation directory rather than working directory

Tags: node.js, babeljs

My `babel.config.js` file is this:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        './babelPlugin.js'
    ],
    presets: [
        '@babel/env'
    ]
} ;
```

Then, if run the command `babel testInput.js -o testOutput.js` from Nodejs installation directory `D:\App files\Node.js\`, everything works fine.

But if I run the same command from my project directory `D:\Projects\Babel plugin test\`, I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env' from 'D:\Projects\Babel plugin test'
```

How can I configure Babel so that it looks for modules in Nodejs's installation directory?

I'm using Babel 7.1.

---

Also, I added `D:\App files\Node.js\` to the `PATH` shell variable.

Comment: Any reason you can't change the working directory with `cd` first? I've thought about adding a `--cwd` option to the CLI, but there isn't one at the moment, so that's the only option at the moment.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, if I did that, my project files wouldn't be in the working directory and I would have to pass the full path to the input and output files. I guess I'll have to solve that with a helper batch script. As a long term solution I would suggest that Babel looks for modules in the working directory first and then, if not found there, look into the install directory.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand your folder structure. How are `App files\Node.js` and `Projects\Babel plugin test` related? `@babel/preset-env` should be installed relative to the config file. Maybe elaborate in the question?

Comment: @loganfsmyth, both directories are unrelated to each other. In order to compile from `D:\App files\Node.js` I copied my project files to that folder. It was just to see if babel would work when the working directory was the same as the install directory. Right now I can make it work by typing `babel "D:\Projects\Babel plugin test\testInput.js" -o "D:\Projects\Babel plugin test\testOutput.js"`. But I was trying to avoid typing the full file paths.

Comment: It's generally best to update the question with info like this rather than posting large comments. I still don't follow which files got copied where and why. Babel will look for `preset-env` relative to the config file that references it. Was the config file copied? Which folder has `preset-env` installed and which doesn't? A complete description of your folder structure would go a long way.